# Moving an element with InsertAfter, but only insert it the parent of the elements?

Tags: jquery

I did the following:

```
  jQuery('.businessdirectory-category .wpbdp-rating-info').insertAfter('.businessdirectory-category .title');
```

To move `.wpbdp-rating-info` after `.title`. But there are 3 `.wpbdp-rating-info` in the page so now each `.businessdirectory-category` has 3 `.wpbdp-rating-info`

How can I do it so that each `.businessdirectory-category` only has its own .wpbdp-rating-info`appended to its own`.title`?

EDIT:

[image]

I changed it to this:

```
 jQuery('.wpbdp-listing-excerpt .wpbdp-rating-info').each(function () {
    var $this = jQuery(this);
    $this.insertAfter($this.closest('.wpbdp-listing-excerpt').find('.title'));
  });
```

But didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the matched set and move each element individually:

```
jQuery('.businessdirectory-category .wpbdp-rating-info').each(function () {
    var $this = jQuery(this);
    $this.insertAfter($this.closest('.businessdirectory-category').find('.title'));
});
```

You may be able to simplify the argument to `insertAfter`, but you'd need to post your markup for me to know for sure. This example assumes that the `.title` element is not a sibling or ancestor of `.businessdirectory-category`.

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/jamesallardice/Asuyy/).

Comment: Thanks! but strange, it didn't seem to work. Maybe you need to know the structure? (Please see my EDIT). Maybe because WordPress doens't allow the dollar sign?

Comment: According to your DOM structure, `.wpbdp-listing-excerpt` doesn't exist. The element has two class names, `wpbdp-listing` and `excerpt`. You could pass `.listing-details` to `.closest()` though, since it's not as far up the DOM tree.

Comment: Oh, it is there (just that the screenshot is too small). I'm getting this: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input` in the console though.

Comment: Chances are that you've missed a closing `)` or `}` elsewhere in your script. The snippet you've added to your question is fine and should work.

Comment: Mmm...I'm getting this: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
jquery.cycle.all.js:25[cycle] terminating; zero elements found by selector` it means that a selector is wrong?

Comment: Oh you were right. Missed a closing bracket. Sorry, my brain is not working well today.